# Deserialize JSON Object C# prob

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following snippet of Json:

```
Article: [
{
@attributes: {
id: "10819"
},
title: "Weekend Guide and Previews",
county1: { },
county2: { },
newsid: "10819",
sections: {
section_id: [
"13",
"1"
]
},
content_text_id: "8561",
content_image_id: "6626",
content_video: "NONE",
upload_date: "2014-08-22 10:16:39",
filename: "http://www.gaa.ie/content/images/news/mayo/OSheaAidan_v_Kerry.jpg",
thumbnail: "http://www.gaa.ie/content/content_thumbs/Images/news/mayo/OSheaAidan_v_Kerry.jpg",
url: "http://www.gaa.ie/gaa-news-and-videos/daily-news/1/2208141016-weekend-guide-and-previews/1/"
},
{
@attributes: {
id: "10825"
},
title: "Press Release: Weekend Travel Information",
county1: { },
county2: { },
newsid: "10825",
sections: {
section_id: [
"13",
"1"
]
},
content_text_id: "8567",
content_image_id: "6396",
content_video: "NONE",
upload_date: "2014-08-22 17:05:13",
filename: "http://www.gaa.ie/content/images/news/croke_park/CrokePark_general_view2014.jpg",
thumbnail: "http://www.gaa.ie/content/content_thumbs/Images/news/croke_park/CrokePark_general_view2014.jpg",
url: "http://www.gaa.ie/gaa-news-and-videos/daily-news/1/2208141705-press-release-weekend-travel-information/1/"
}
]
```

and the following Article class:

```
public class Article
    {
        public int newsid { get; set; }
        public String title { get; set; }
        public String content_text_id { get; set; }
        public String content_image_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime upload_date { get; set; }
        public String filename { get; set; }
        public String thumbnail { get; set; }
        public String url { get; set; }
        public String content_video { get; set; }

    }
```

I am trying to deserialize the json to articles as follows:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Article>>(json);
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication2.Models.Article]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

I also have trouble understanding the property called @attributes? Although is not necessary for me, as is the sections property.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: http://jsonlint.com might also come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems

Arrays in [json](http://json.org/) should be defined as

[image]

But your json is not an array definition. It's even not object definition. To make it valid array definition you should remove `Article:` from your json.

Second problem is `@` characters. JSON.NET not works with them, so you should remove or replace these characters:

```
json = json.Replace("Article:", "").Replace("@attributes", "attributes");
var articles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Article>>(json);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Also none of the identifiers are in quotes. I'm not sure if that library will have a problem with that or not.

Comment: @mafafu it's not a problem - JSON.NET works fine with it. Added screenshot of result

Comment: I thought it might, but technically they should be in quotes I believe.